# Ensuring minimal horizontal space

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm using the `beamer` class and overlays to step-wise modify an equation, e.g. I would transition from something like `x = y` to `abc = y`.

However, I would like to keep the vertical alignment of the `= y` part of the equation, or in other words, I would like to automatically have enough space after `x` added, so that it occupies the same space as the thing `abc` it is being replaced with.

How can I achieve that? Is it e.g. possible to have invisible rows in a table that occupy no vertical space but are still used for alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` to put various `<stuff>` with the same `<tag>` in boxes of maximum (similar) width. The default `<align>`ment is `c`entred:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  $\only<1>{\eqmakebox[LHS]{$x$}}
   \only<2>{\eqmakebox[LHS]{$abc$}}
   = y$
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

`\eqmakebox` stores the largest width in the `.aux` file, and therefore requires at least two compilations with every change in the widest element.